# Can zoomControl ControlPosition be defined with CSS?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know there a [fixed position](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=it#ControlPosition) for the zoomControl, but they are not enough for where I need to put it.

Can I style it with CSS? Such as `top:80px; right:20px;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it with **jQuery**. If you see the HTML source for the map generated, it can be observed that the various controls the map provides don't have a ID attribute to manipulate them. However we can use the title attribute of each element to modify them as per our need. See this solution where in a click on the map div adds a `top:50px` to the bar in zoom control -

**[**DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dKBqs/2/)**

**jQuery-**

```
$("div[title='Click to zoom']").css("top","50px");
        });
```

Similarly you can capture other controls in the map and add css to them as per your need.

One point to note here is that you can't us the `$(document).ready()` to change the css on page load since the map actually takes time to load and by then the zoom bar isn't in the `DOM`. So I used a map `click` event to add the css. You can use other events to manipulate the css of the zoom control or other controls.

Comment: This is a good workaround, but will fails in the future if Google change a little bit "title" content! Thank you anyway...

Comment: Yes. The important point here is that you are trying to control something on which you are not provided control of, so any solution cannot be completely reliable. If you feel the workaround was good you can mark it too.